# What is the difference between a Native API and a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, native, api-design

I'm trying to figure out the difference between a Native API and a RESTful API. I cannot get a comprehensive definition of a Native API. does it use the same request/response get/post methods like REST?

Comment: Can you please give us a bit of context?

Comment: I just want a clear definition of a Native API. i understand what a RESTful API is but cannot seem to find a definition of Native APIs.